# C#'s equivalent to VB.NET's DirectCast

Tags: c#, vb.net, casting, directcast, ctype

Does C# have an equivalent to VB.NET's DirectCast?

I am aware that it has () casts and the 'as' keyword, but those line up to CType and TryCast.

To be clear, these keywords do the following;

**CType/() casts**:  If it is already the correct type, cast it, otherwise look for a type converter and invoke it. If no type converter is found, throw an InvalidCastException.

**TryCast/"as" keyword**: If it is the correct type, cast it, otherwise return null.

**DirectCast**: If it is the correct type, cast it, otherwise throw an InvalidCastException.

After I have spelled out the above, some people have still responded that () is equivalent, so I will expand further upon why this is not true.

DirectCast only allows for either narrowing or widening conversions on the inheritance tree. It does not support conversions across different branches like () does, i.e.:

C# - this compiles and runs:

```cs
//This code uses a type converter to go across an inheritance tree
double d = 10;
int i = (int)d;
```

VB.NET - this does NOT COMPILE

```vb
'Direct cast can only go up or down a branch, never across to a different one.
Dim d As Double = 10
Dim i As Integer = DirectCast(d, Integer)
```

The equivalent in VB.NET to my C# code is CType:

```vb
'This compiles and runs
Dim d As Double = 10
Dim i As Integer = CType(d, Integer)
```

Comment: +1 for defining the keywords and not making people look it up.

Comment: `string s = "10"; int i = (int)s;` does not compile in C#.

Comment: Have you tried using reflector to compare the MSIL?

Comment: @Robert: Oops! I rewrote with double... and actually ran my code through compilers this time :)

Comment: @Robert Davis:  I think Collin Suave is not trying to run in Visual Studio his assumptions

Comment: @csauve: You're mistaken about what the keywords do. While `int i = (int)d;` may perform a known conversion for a known type as in your example code, in any scenario where you'd *realistically* use `DirectCast` in VB.NET (i.e., when an object's type is not known at compile time), casting with `()` in C# does *not* perform a conversion -- it *just* casts. So a boxed double cannot be unboxed as an integer. For this reason the two are effectively equivalent.

Comment: @csauve: On the example you give, DirectCast is a **false security blanket** that is **not worn all the time**. First of all, if you really need to cast your variable to another **compatible type**, DirectCast is of no use. See my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683847/cs-equivalent-to-vb-nets-directcast/2685782#2685782

Comment: I believe you might be interested in the `System.Type` method `IsAssignableFrom`.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why do you *need* this?

Comment: Your statements about how `()` is different than `DirectCast` are correct for *value* types, but incorrect for *reference* types. [The two are equivalent for reference types; no conversion is performed.] Which makes it a pointless comparison, because, IMHO, there is no reason to use `DirectCast` with a *value* type. The way I see it:  `()` is equivalent to `CType` for value types, and to `DirectCast` for reference types.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems clear that the functionality you want is not in C#. Try this though...

```
static T DirectCast<T>(object o, Type type) where T : class
{
    if (!(type.IsInstanceOfType(o)))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    T value = o as T;
    if (value == null && o != null)
    {
        throw new InvalidCastException();
    }
    return value;
}
```

Or, even though it is different from the VB, call it like:

```
static T DirectCast<T>(object o) where T : class
{
    T value = o as T;
    if (value == null && o != null)
    {
        throw new InvalidCastException();
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: agrees with what I originally thought.  Thanks.

Comment: You can remove the `T : class` requirement if you use `is` instead of `as`.

`static T DirectCast<T>(object o) { if(o != null && o is T) return (T)o; else throw new InvalidCastException(); }`

Comment: In your code you don't use the "type" parameter, so you can leave it out. Or use it in an extra check: if (typeof(T) != type) throw new InvalidArgumentException(...);.

Comment: I was just noticing that same fact.

Comment: @Robert Davis: The where T : class is in there so I can use the 'as'.  Using return(T)o seems to go against what csuave wants to accomplish.

Comment: @gbogumil, I would agree with Robert on this, you can use return (T)o at that point, because you can be absolutely sure that o is T -- it is impossible for the clr/compiler to funge things up and do type conversions.

Comment: I believe the equivalent of `DirectCast` actually *is* available in C#--just split into two different usages depending on the scenario. See my answer.

Comment: @gbogumil: I don't mean to be antagonistic, but I think this answer is pretty misleading and misses the true relationship between `DirectCast` in VB.NET and casting in C#. Take a look at my answer and let me know what you think.

Comment: @Robert Davis: Actually, the type checks on `o` are not necessary at all since `(T)o` will already throw an `InvalidCastException` if the types don't match up. With that in mind, the real equivalent code would just be `return (T)o;`, which makes it clear that the method itself could really just be the equivalent of `(T)(object)value`. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: @Dan Tao: You're right. Since it's impossible for a type to create an implicit/explicit operator from object, `(T)(object)value` will never call any conversion functions.

Comment: I don't think that `type is T` check does what you think it does.  It's quite wrong, in fact.  You're probably looking for `type.IsInstanceOfType(o)`.  Combining `is` with `as` is also redundant.

Comment: This answer is very misleading indeed.  When does `!(type is T)` ever return true?? Answer: probably not when you think.  This statement is actually testing for when T is not a base class or interface of `System.Type` (not the corresponding type specified by the instance `type`, which I think was the intent).

Comment: When working with *reference* types, C#'s `(SomeReferenceType)` *is* `DirectCast`. See "A cast operation between reference types does not change the run-time type of the underlying object; ..." in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions. That is to say, for *reference* types, that syntax *never does any conversion*. Therefore, given that you have the constraint `where T : class`, this code is unnecessary; simply use `(SomeReferenceType)`

Answer (score 8):

**SECOND UPDATE**:

OK, here's a C# method that's been proposed to allegedly do basically what `DirectCast` does in VB.NET.

```cs
static T DirectCast<T>(object o) where T : class
{
    T value = o as T;
    if (value == null && o != null)
    {
        throw new InvalidCastException();
    }
    return value;
}
```

**Here are the problems with the above method:**

1. It has a `where T : class` constraint, which `DirectCast` does not.
2. It boxes its argument as a `System.Object` -- again, not true of `DirectCast` (at least not that I'm aware of).
3. It uses `as` unnecessarily (which is why it has the `class` constraint in the first place); calling `(T)o` will throw an `InvalidCastException` if it doesn't work; why check if the value matches up using `as`, only to throw the same exception that would've been thrown if you'd gone the `(T)o` route to begin with?

The method could really be rewritten to provide the same results as `DirectCast` as follows:

```cs
static T DirectCast<T>(object o) {
    return (T)o;
}
```

Funny observation: really all this method is doing is boxing a value and then attempting to unbox it. In other words, `DirectCast<int>(12.0)` would really be the same as `(int)(object)12.0` (and either would throw an exception). Realizing this makes the proposed `DirectCast<T>` method pretty unnecessary altogether.

Now, here's an example of how `DirectCast` and casting with `()` are "different" between VB.NET and C#:

VB:

```vb
Dim i As Integer = 12
Dim l As Long = DirectCast(i, Long) ' does not compile '
```

C#:

```cs
int i = 12;
long l = i; // DOES compile
```

OK, so one compiles, the other doesn't. But look at that code. **What's the point of `DirectCast` when you already know an object's type?** This is not a realistic comparison, because in VB.NET there'd never be any reason to call `DirectCast` like the code above does. (If you wanted to convert a value *known to be of type `System.Int32`* to a value of type `System.Int64` in VB.NET, you'd use `CLng`, not `DirectCast`.) If there were a variable typed as `System.Object` in there, **then** it would make sense to use `DirectCast`, and the below code would indeed be equivalent:

VB:

```vb
Dim i As Integer = 12
Dim o As Object = i
Dim l As Long = DirectCast(o, Long) ' compiles, throws an exception '
```

C#:

```cs
int i = 12;
object o = i;
long l = (long)o; // compiles, throws an exception
```

So I maintain that `DirectCast` in VB.NET, in any scenario in which it actually makes sense to use it (i.e., when the type of an object is not known at compile time), **is the same as a straight `()`-style cast in C#**.

---

**EDIT**: Well, shame on me for posting some VB code that didn't compile. After reconsidering what I was saying, I withdraw my *second* answer but maintain the first.

If you're referring to the usage of `DirectCast` where you take an object of unknown type and try to cast it to the desired type, then it *is* the same as C#'s () cast:

VB:

```vb
Dim o As Object = SomeObject()
Dim i As Integer = DirectCast(o, Integer)
```

C#:

```cs
object o = SomeObject();
int i = (int)o;
```

This is because, if `o` is typed as a `System.Object`, then the `()` operation in C# will attempt to unbox it. This will fail if the types don't match exactly; for instance, if `o` is a boxed `System.Double`, then `(int)o` will throw an exception because `o` **must** be unboxed as a `System.Double` before it can be converted to a `System.Int32` (if you don't believe me, try it out for yourself!).

---

*Note: the below is inaccurate because `DirectCast` does **not** perform widening conversions; in any case, I'm leaving it for posterity.*

On the other hand, when dealing with widening vs. narrowing conversions, using the `()` operation in C# does more work than simply casting, as you've pointed out (i.e., you can do `(int)someDouble`). In this scenario, `DirectCast` is equivalent to plain old assignment in C#:

VB:

```vb
Dim i As Integer = 12
Dim l As Long = DirectCast(i, Long) ' does not compile, actually '
```

C#:

```cs
int i = 12;
long l = i;
```

Comment: You're vb code doesn't compile.  I'm assuming that instead of 12 as the type param to directcast you meant long, but that doesn't compile either.  Also make sure that option strict is on, or else youre going to get a crap-ton of implicit conversions (the vb compiler likes to read minds)

Comment: @csauve: Good call. That was stupid of me! In any case, take a look at my first point. I do believe that `DirectCast` is really the same as C#'s `()` operation when used on objects typed as `System.Object`.

Comment: @csauve: By the way, regarding Option Strict... in the code I originally posted, Option *Infer* works just as well. (I've added the types anyway, for completeness.)

Answer (score 1):

Actually the compiler just catches the DirectCast violation if it infers that the typed variable cannot be converted to the other type.

These are the actual equivalents:

```csharp
double d = 10;
int i = (int)d;
```

```vbnet
Dim d As Double = 10
Dim i As Integer = d
```

Note the dangerousness of this construct. When you just merely assign double to integer in VB.NET, the double will be accidentally downsized to integer.

Whereas C# programmers get the compile-time safety of not accidentally downsizing a variable in .NET.  VB.NET programmers have to contend with always using DirectCast as a safe programming habit.

These are the actual equivalents:

```csharp
// Will not compile, cannot convert double to int

double d = 10;
int i = d;
```

```vbnet
' Will not compile, cannot convert double to int

Dim d As Double = 10
Dim i As Integer = DirectCast(d, Integer)
```

Regarding [Dan Tao's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683847/cs-equivalent-to-vb-nets-directcast/52401238#comment2704735_2684519):

There's no need to use DirectCast in C#. The runtime also prevents loading of long to integer value.  This is what the OP is contending, that C# doesn't have DirectCast, that DirectCast can prevent assigning of different types of variable, whereas "because" C# doesn't have this DirectCast, it will silently error on assigning different types.  But as you can see, that's not the case. C#'s casting is **exactly** the same as DirectCast.  This will cause a **InvalidCastException** runtime error:

```csharp
long l = 10;
object o = l;
int i = (int)o;
```

This will also cause the same *runtime error* as above:

```vbnet
Dim l As Long = 10
Dim o As Object = l
Dim i As Integer = DirectCast(o, Integer)
```

Now, this is where the "fun" part comes in. With VB.NET you have to remember many keywords in order to accomplish something.  In C#, if a given keyword could be used in another scenario (like in this one downcasting of variable), they will not invent another keyword just to make it happen.

In C# you just have to do this:

```csharp
long l = 10;
object o = l;
int i = (int)(long)o;
```

In VB.NET if you really want to downcast the variable, and want the orthogonal way to do it, i.e. just remembering one keyword, you must do this:

```vbnet
Dim l As Long = 10
Dim o As Object = l
Dim i As Integer = DirectCast(DirectCast(o, Long), Integer)
```

But that will not compile, so how can we achieve downcasting long to integer? You must remember VB.NET's other keywords.  Whereas in C#, it's orthogonal, you unbox variable using this construct `(typehere)`, you also downcast/upcast using same construct `(typehere)`. In VB.NET there's a fundamental disconnect between loading a value from object and downcasting it.  So in VB.NET, you have to do this:

```vbnet
Dim l As Long = 10
Dim o As Object = l
Dim i As Integer = CType(o, Integer)
```

---

Hmm.. I think the OP's confusion stems from C# multiple use of `(typehere)`. First, it is used for downcasting; second, the same construct (check the first part of this post, `object o = l`) is also used for unboxing of value from object, which, rest assured, it has DirectCast's safe type conversion behavior. They are the same!

This downcasting...

```csharp
long l = 1;
int i = (int) l;
```

...is not equivalent to:

```vbnet
Dim l As Long = 1
Dim i As Integer = DirectCast(l, Integer)
```

If you want to perform downcasting, you have to do this:

```vbnet
Dim l As Long = 1
Dim i As Integer = CInt(l) ' Can also use CType
```

Now, if a VB.NET programmer is programming by intent, and not sleepy while coding, why will he/she use DirectCast when he/she is fully aware that it cannot assign different types? If what the VB.NET programmer really wanted is to downcast, he/she should not attempt DirectCast in the first place.  Now the VB.NET programmer, upon discovering that DirectCast cannot be used for downcasting, must backspace what he/she has written and replace it with CInt (or CType).

Comment: Try turning Option Strict On -- I would hope that most shops force any vb devs to write with it on.

Comment: @Michael: This is what I thought, too; but as csauve pointed out in a comment to my answer, the code examples at the end of your answer are actually not equivalents. A `long` *can* be assigned to an `int` in C#, but VB.NET will not allow a `Long` to be assigned to an `Integer` using `DirectCast`.

Comment: @Dan Tao - See my comment above

Comment: Our answers have somewhat converged ;) But my point was specifically in response to your code `double d = 10; int i = d;` -- you rightly commented that it would not compile, just as `DirectCast(d, Integer)` would not compile; *on the other hand*, in C#, `int i = 10; long l = i;` *will* compile in C#, but `DirectCast(i, Long)` will not. Otherwise, I think we're completely on the same page.

Comment: @Dan Tao: regarding DirectCast(i, Long). I think VB.NET language designers doesn't want their programmers to suffer.  Why they will not allow VB.NET programmers to use this (they allow)? --> Dim l As Long = i.  I think all in all, DirectCast are just meant to be backspaced when they are accidentally used(because of wrong usage expectation) by programmers, when what they really meant after all is CInt/CLng, CType, etc

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it yourself:

```
static T CastTo<T>(this object obj) { return (T)obj; }
```

Use it as follows:

```
3.5.CastTo<int>(); //throws InvalidCastException.
```

This works and doesn't involve user-defined converters because of the fact that generics are "resolved" at runtime, but type conversions are resolved at compile-time - the framework doesn't actually generate distinct implementations for each `T`, but rather shares the implementation for similar `T`, and hence the runtime doesn't have the information to resolve the custom conversions.

Answer (score 1):

VB.NET:

```vbnet
Dim xxx as label = Directcast(sender, label)
```

C#:

```csharp
label xxx = (label)sender;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please explain your code and how this code solves the problem.

Comment: You would do well to read the question in full as well as the existing answers when you are necroing an 8-year old question.

Answer (score 0):

You have two types of cast in C#. Without additional code there is no equivalent to the DirectCast keyword in C#. The closest you have without creating it yourself is to use `()`.

You have:

```
My_Object c = (My_Object)object
```

and

```
My_Object c = object as My_Object
```

In the first one, if the cast fails, it throws an error. You are saying, "I know what this object is, and if it is not, there is something wrong."

In the second, `c` is assigned the value null where possible (null can't be assigned to value types). In this one you are saying "I think I know what this one is, but if not don't throw an error, because nothing might be wrong."

Other post explaining casting:

*[What is the difference between explicit and implicit type casts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584293/what-is-the-difference-between-explicit-and-implicit-type-cast)*

Comment: oops I got my terminology mixed up.  Thanks

Comment: As stated above, () casts allow for type converters, DirectCast does not.

Answer (score 0):

Did you really try to run your sample code?

Regarding...

```
//This code uses a type converter to go across an inheritance tree
string s = "10";
int i = (int)s;
```

...You posited that it will run.  It also does not run.

Comment: I've editted it to use doubles.  I had the illconceived notion that  string->int was legal in c#.  double->int shoudl work

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to give a shot at this.

First, let me be clear on this. This **WILL NOT** compile:

```
//This code uses a type converter to go across an inheritance tree
string s = "10";
int i = (int)s;
```

---

### VB's CType

In VB, you would use:

```
Dim s as String = "10"
Dim i as Integer = CType(s, Integer)
```

In C#, I would use:

```
string s = "10";
int i = Convert.ToInt32(s);
```

---

### VB's DirectCast

> If it is the correct type, cast it,
>   otherwise throw an
>   InvalidCastException.
>
> Direct cast can only go up or down a
>   branch, never across to a different
>   one.

From that explanation, it would be a direct equivalent of the C# cast. However in C# you would only need to specify the cast operator only for casting down. Casting up is totally optional. Example:

```
// casting down
object t = "some random string needing to be casted down";
string s = (string) t;
// casting up
object a = s;
// explicitly casting up although it's totally optional
object b = (object) s;
```

C# cast does not look for any Type Converter. It will only look for any defined explicit / implicit operator overload for the type you are trying to cast to.

---

### VB's TryCast

You already understood correctly that this is equivalent to C# as keyword.

Comment: C# () cast allows type converters.  DirectCast does not.  Replace string with double and you will see.  C# allows double->int using () cast, vb.net does not allow it with directcast, only with ctype.

Comment: () cast does not use type converters. It acts on the IConvertible interface. See for yourself on MSDN's TypeConverter page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx. There's no single example showing that you are able to use C# cast to trigger the usage of TypeConverters.

Comment: You are correct, and I was wrong, that "C# cast does not look for any Type Converter. It will only look for any defined explicit / implicit operator overload for the type you are trying to cast to."

Which makes it a thing all to its own - its not quite a ctype, and not quite a directcast.

Answer (score 0):

`DirectCast` and `()` do not always generate the same CIL, so I think this is a difference between the VB and C# compilers.

As far as I can tell, reference types get cast using the `castclass` CIL instruction, while for value types the compiler generates the relevant CIL depending on the input types.

In C#, casting from `double` to `integer` emits the `conv.i4` CIL instruction, which will cheerfully overwrite the sign bit or whatever in the output, if the value is too large. In Visual Basic, it's a compilation error.

Interestingly, if you use an intermediate `object` variable to hold the double, then the cast will fail for both C# and Visual Basic... but at runtime. Both compilers emit an `unbox` instruction instead of trying to do a conversion.

Answer (score -1):

The () casting should be the same; it throws an InvalidCastException. Just try this in C#:

```
 string t = "hello";
 object x = t;
 int j = (int) x;
```

Comment: Yes, but the "(int) x" is actually attempting to convert a string to int, so if t = "10" it would succeed.  DirectCast does not allow for type converters, so even if t = "10" it would still fail.

Comment: @Collin Sauve: I'm not sure where you got that idea from, but it's wrong. It simply won't compile if you try to do int j = (int) t where t = "10".

Comment: sorry. strings are just a bad example.  double->int is a better one.  double d = 10; int i = (int)d;  this is all well and good in c#, but if i replace the (int)d with directcast(d,integer) it doesn't work in vb.net

Comment: I think Collin Sauve is not trying to run the assumed non-counterpart of C# from VB.NET.  If t = "10" (string), the above code will also result to **InvalidCastException**.  @CollinSauve: please do run the code in Visual Studio before making assumptions

Answer (score -1):

I think this scenario sums it up best why DirectCast has a false sense of compile-time type checking security for non-object (object keyword) type, and is just meant to be backspaced.

```csharp
float f = 10;
long l = f;
```

```vbnet
Option Strict On
Dim f As Single = 10
Dim l As Long = f
```

A C# coder, upon discovering that float is not directly assignable to long and won't compile, will do this:

```csharp
long l = (long)f;
```

Which is correct.

Now, let's turn to our VB.NET coder, upon discovering that float is not assignable to long and won't compile, will attempt this:

```vbnet
Dim l As Long = DirectCast(f, Long)
```

A few seconds later...

VB.NET programmer: "Please let me do my bidding, please compile, please...!!!"

After some Googling-fu and MSDN-browsing moments later:

VB.NET programmer: "Ah.. so I have to use this CLng or CType construct for casting variables"

```vbnet
Dim l As Long = CLng(f)
```

That is what I meant by DirectCast having a false sense of compile-time type checking security. DirectCast are just meant to be backspaced if a programmer doesn't know when and where they should be used.  DirectCast is a security blanket that is **not worn all the time.**

How useful is DirectCast in this scenario if it will not be used after all?

---

**[EDIT]**

@Jules

I'm not purporting that all VB.NET programmers don't know what's the real use of DirectCast. Some of them really do know that DirectCast are just meant to be used for object types (and primitive types that are boxed in object) only.

One scenario where a VB.NET coder recoding existing C# code to VB.NET one will arrive at wrong conclusion, is with expected (be it rightly or not) languages symmetry to each other.

When he/she sees in the code this construct...

```vbnet
TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
```

...He/she will translate that to this:

```vbnet
Dim txt As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
```

Which is correct.

Now, because we programmers love symmetry, some of us (I might be too if I don't know CLng) will tend to convert this code...

```csharp
/* Numbers are stored in file as float(component's file structure
is designed by 3rd party company) */
float f = file.ReadFloat(0);
long l = (long)f; // But we don't care about using the fractional part
```

...to this:

```vbnet
Dim f As Single = file.ReadFloat(0)
Dim l As Long = DirectCast(f, Long)
```

If a C# person is the one converting C# code to VB.NET, he will be frustrated for apparent lack of symmetry here.

But for a VB.NET person tasked to convert C# code to VB.NET, he will get the impression that C# compiler doesn't catches incompatible type assignments, while VB.NET catches it.  Now, for that apparent discovery, will brag that VB.NET feature to his colleagues and some forums.

But lest be the VB.NET programmer makes the mistake of wrongly inferring the intent of first code.  The C#'s code fragment above <strike>started its life like this</strike> was initially written like this:

```csharp
float f = file.ReadFloat(0);
long l = f;
```

And that will not compile, C# compiler **catches** incompatible type assignments, in the same vein that the equivalent VB.NET with `Option Strict On` will also not compile that (albeit will only not compile when `Option Strict` is set to `On`, too lenient).  So we need  to typecast float to long using `(long)`.  Becomes this: `long l = (long)f;`

Now for casting one variable type to another compatible type, in the same vein that we convert this code...

```csharp
TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
```

...to this code:

```vbnet
Dim txt As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, Textbox)
```

We must convert this code...

```csharp
long l = (long)f; // Will compile
```

...to this code:

```vbnet
Dim l As Long = DirectCast(f, Long) ' Will not compile
```

But alas, that will not compile. On casting between compatible primitive types, this is where DirectCast fells short in.  It doesn't offer any symmetry to the C# code above, and it cannot be used on casting compatible primitive types, despite its name Direct**Cast**.

The way I see it, DirectCast should be named **CastObject**, since it can only cast between object types (and also primitive types that are boxed in object) anyhow. DirectCast really has no business with assigning compatible primitive types (integer, double, and their lower and higher counterpart). When assigning between compatible primitive types, DirectCast ceases to be useful, especially you will backspace it anyhow, and replace it with proper one.

Or the other way I see it, DirectCast construct should be amended, so it can cast compatible types like the way old and newer languages do ever since, e.g., C, C++, C#, Java, Delphi, D, etc.  Doing this, it will offer VB.NET significant symmetry to other languages when it comes to type casting.  Doing this, we can also throw away (hypothetically only, we cannot make other programs fail that rely on old functions) all plethora of functions which names doesn't directly maps to its types (e.g., CInt, CDbl, CSng, etc.). We will just use DirectCast in lieu of them.

Comment: What are you talking about?? I know exactly when and when not to use DirectCast. You may as well say a VB.Net coder types: Dim l as long = Gosub(f, Long)!