# What is the C# equivalent of CType in VB.NET?

Tags: casting, equivalent, vb.net-to-c#, ctype

I am trying to convert the example provided in MSDN article *[Creating Dynamic Data Entry User Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479330.aspx)* to C#, but am stuck at the following code:

```
CType(dq, IUIBuildingBlock).QuestionText = reader("QuestionText")
```

How do I convert the above VB.NET statement to C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#'s equivalent to VB.Net's DirectCast?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683847/cs-equivalent-to-vb-nets-directcast)

Comment: @Joel: I think that question ends up *including* the answer to this one, but it's ostensibly about `DirectCast` rather than `CType`, so I'm not voting to close.

Comment: @Cody Gray - that's precisely why I voted to close. By searching with his question, I was able to find one that included his answer. While the question itself may not be an "exact" duplicate, the information he seeks is there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**In C#, you can specify a cast by putting the type you want to cast to in parenthesis in front of the reference variable that you want to cast (`(type)instance`).**

So, to cast the object (`dq`) to the type `IUIBuildingBlock`, you could use the following code:

```
((IUIBuildingBlock)dq).QuestionText = reader("QuestionText");
```

(Note that this will throw an exception if the cast is done on an object that doesn't implement `IUIBuildingBlock`, but so will `CType`, so I assume that is not a problem.)

Comment: For those wondering about the differences between C# (int), and VB's CINT, and DirectCast(x, integer).  The answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056514/difference-between-directcast-and-ctype-in-vb-net is very helpful