# VB vs C# — CType vs ChangeType

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Why does this work in VB.Net:

```
Dim ClipboardStream As New StreamReader(
    CType(ClipboardData.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue), Stream))
```

But this is throwing an error in C#:

> Stream is a Type, which is not valid in the current context

```
ClipboardStream = new StreamReader(Convert.ChangeType(
    ClipboardData.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue), Stream));
```

To be honest, I'm not 100% clued up on converting types, I've only ever used them in code snippets and now I'm trying to convert a simple VB code snippet to a C# version...

Comment: So many great answers in about 5 minutes - thanks all!! I'll up-vote all but I have to accept @Sweeper 's answer since it helped me *understand* the difference the most.

Comment: `ClipboardData.GetData()` looks like Javascript :)

Comment: I assume the guy who originally coded this in VB was a Javascript fan.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ChangeType` accepts a `Type` as the second parameter, so you should write `typeof(Stream)`. `typeof(Stream)` evaluates to a `Type` instance representing the type `Stream`. Just using `Stream` there does not work because it does not evaluate to a value. It's not an expression.

Anyway, you shouldn't be using `ChangeType` here anyway, you should *cast*, which is the [C# equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409082/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-ctype-in-vb-net) of `CType`:

```
 ClipboardStream = new StreamReader((Stream)ClipboardData.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue));
```

Comment: No, C#'s cast is equivalent to VB's `DirectCast`. `CType` potentially performs conversion between convertible types. For example `var myString = (string)myInt` doesn't even compile, neither does `myInt as string`, but `Ctype(myInt, String)` is perfectly legal and works.

Answer (score 8):

`CType` is a compiler function in VB.Net. It allows its second argument to be an expression that yields a type name. You cannot write functions like that yourself in either VB or C#.

The C# using `Convert` would be, as Patrick says, be:

```
ClipboardStream = new StreamReader(Convert.ChangeType(
ClipboardData.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue),typeof(Stream)));
```

But this code is closer to if *this* had been written in VB:

```
ClipboardStream = New StreamReader(Convert.ChangeType( _
ClipboardData.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue),GetType(Stream)))
```

`CType` in VB is a lot closer to a *cast* in C# (e.g. `(Stream)...` rather than `CType(..., Stream)`)

Comment: @PatrickHofman - It's the VB equivalent of `typeof`. Working on improving the wording to indicate that second sample *is* VB.

Comment: I don't have an IDE to verify right now, but `GetType()` should be only available right side of a comparison or assignment.

Comment: @Jimi - check the examples (remember to switch to VB) - [Convert.ChangeType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples)

Comment: Well, yes, `Convert.ChangeType()` accepts it. But, then, what kind of type `ClipboardStream` would be? It's a narrowing convertion (if I'm not mistaken), that probably even with Option Strict off is invalid. I'll check it out.

Comment: But, I was assuming that `ClipboardData.GetData()`, given its parameter, is equivalen to `Clipboard.GetData()`. Which might not be.

Comment: Is `CType` more of a compiler function than `typeof`?

Answer (score 7):

Because passing in a type in C# is different than it is in VB.NET. You should use `typeof(Stream)`:

```
ClipboardStream = new StreamReader
                    ( Convert.ChangeType
                        ( ClipboardData.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue)
                        , typeof(Stream)
                        )
                    );
```

In this case however, a simple cast would be better:

```
ClipboardStream = new StreamReader
                    ( (Stream)ClipboardData.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue)
                    );
```

Comment: Thanks. Was just looking around and saw the `typeof` on a few code examples on MSDN and was about to try it. I don't understand casting either, but it works perfectly so I'll use that and try to do some reading on it ASAP :)

Comment: This is incorrect. If you were to use `Convert.ChangeType` in VB.NET you also couldn't pass in a type name; you'd have to pass in a type instance. Like C#'s `typeof` operator, which gets a `Type` instance from a type name, VB.NET has the `GetType` operator: `Convert.ChangeType(ClipboardData.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue), GetType(Stream))`.

Answer (score 5):

`Convert.ChangeType` expects a `Type` argument in its second parameter. To obtain the `Type` instance from a variable, call the `GetType()` method or use the `typeof` operator:

```
ClipboardStream = new StreamReader(Convert.ChangeType(
ClipboardData.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue), Stream.GetType()));


ClipboardStream = new StreamReader(Convert.ChangeType(
ClipboardData.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue), typeof(Stream)));
```

Another way (imo the preferred way) is to use the casting operator

```
ClipboardStream = new StreamReader((Stream)ClipboardData.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue));
```