# .NET - How is explicit cast with "as" different (internally) from (someType)someobject, and why?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, explicit

I understand that when you use an explicit cast like this:

```
(someType)someobject
```

you can get an invalid cast exception if `someobject` is not really `someType`.

As well I understand that when you cast with `as` like this:

```
myObject = someObject as someType
```

`myObject` is just rendered `null` if `someObject` isn't really `someType`.

How are these evaluated differently and why?

Comment: [Answer from Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/08/what-s-the-difference-between-as-and-cast-operators.aspx) and here is [another similar question on SO(but not exact duplicate)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584293/what-is-the-difference-between-explicit-and-implicit-type-cast)

Comment: You are slightly incorrect: `var myObject = someObject as someType`, where `myObject` is null if the cast fails.

Comment: Ooops, thanks, fixed in question now.

Answer (score 7):

John Skeet has a [C# faq](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/faq/#parameters) where he explains the differences between the two operators. See paragraph 'What's the difference between using cast syntax and the `as` operator?'.

Quote :

> Using the `as` operator differs from a
> cast in C# in three important ways:
>
> 1. It returns `null` when the variable you are trying to convert is
>    not of the requested type or in its
>    inheritance chain, instead of throwing
>    an exception.
> 2. It can only be applied to reference type variables converting to
>    reference types.
> 3. Using `as` will not perform user-defined conversions, such as
>    implicit or explicit conversion
>    operators, which casting syntax will
>    do.
>
> There are in fact two completely
> different operations defined in IL
> that handle these two keywords (the
> `castclass` and `isinst` instructions) -
> it's not just "syntactic sugar"
> written by C# to get this different
> behavior. The `as` operator appears to
> be slightly faster in v1.0 and v1.1 of
> Microsoft's CLR compared to casting
> (even in cases where there are no
> invalid casts which would severely
> lower casting's performance due to
> exceptions).

Comment: Awesome FAQ, added to favorites!

Comment: @Richard: Bear in mind that I haven't updated that FAQ in *years*.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the warning. Maybe just use that as a jumping off point for some things then.

Answer (score 0):

Years have passed... but minutes ago I came across a practical example I think is worth noting - of the difference between the two:

Check this out:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GenericCaster<string>(12345));
        Console.WriteLine(GenericCaster<object>(new { a = 100, b = "string" }) ?? "null");
        Console.WriteLine(GenericCaster<double>(20.4));

        //prints:
        //12345
        //null
        //20.4

        Console.WriteLine(GenericCaster2<string>(12345));
        Console.WriteLine(GenericCaster2<object>(new { a = 100, b = "string" }) ?? "null");

        //will not compile -> 20.4 does not comply due to the type constraint "T : class"
        //Console.WriteLine(GenericCaster2<double>(20.4));

        /*
         * Bottom line: GenericCaster2 will not work with struct types. GenericCaster will.
         */
    }

    static T GenericCaster<T>(object value, T defaultValue = default(T))
    {
        T castedValue;
        try
        {
            castedValue = (T) Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            castedValue = defaultValue;
        }

        return castedValue;
    }

    static T GenericCaster2<T>(object value, T defaultValue = default(T)) where T : class
    {
        T castedValue;
        try
        {
            castedValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T)) as T;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            castedValue = defaultValue;
        }

        return castedValue;
    }
}
```

**Bottom line:** GenericCaster2 will not work with struct types. GenericCaster will.