# Explicit Conversion

Tags: c#, blueprism

Consider the following code:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using OutlookApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;

namespace OutlookInterop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OutlookApp outlookApp = new OutlookApp();
            MailItem mailItem = outlookApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
            mailItem.To = "test@test.com";
            mailItem.Subject = "Test Email Alert";
            mailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><body>Test email body.</body></html>";
            mailItem.Display(false);
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine when I run it on Visual Studio, but when I use it in BluePrism, I get the following compiler error:

```
Page: Send Email Alert c#
Stage: Code1
Type: Error
Action: Validate
Description: Compiler error at line 2: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
Repairable: No
```

I think I have referenced the correct assemblies in BluePrism i.e.:
[image]

And then this is the code inside the actual code stage:

```
    OutlookApp outlookApp = new OutlookApp();
    MailItem mailItem = outlookApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem); //this would be line 2
    mailItem.To = "test@test.com";
    mailItem.Subject = "Test Email Alert";
    mailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><body>Test email body.</body></html>";
    mailItem.Display(false);
```

So, why would that code work on Visual Studio but not in BluePrism? what is this cast that is missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I strongly suspect that the difference is in terms of how the Office library is imported. If you look at the properties for the reference in your Visual Studio project, I suspect it will show that the "Embed Interop Types" property is set to True. This not only embeds the interop types, but also makes methods and properties that would return `object` return `dynamic` instead - which is why the code would compile.

I don't know whether BluePrism has an option for COM libraries like that. If it doesn't, just at an explicit cast to `MailItem`.

Comment: I think you are right. I have imported and used COM libraries in BP before (Excel, Word) but I just never happened to come across this issue when creating instances of those objects.Thank you for the great explanation, is very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

There is no implicit conversion so .Net doesn't know how to convert using simple assignment.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584293/what-is-the-difference-between-explicit-and-implicit-type-casts) for details of implicit vs explicit conversions;

However, the error states that there is an explicit conversion so you'll need to add an explicit cast to your code.

```
MailItem mailItem = (MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
```